# Visualforce encapsulation problem with virtual extended class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a doubt regarding Visualforce.

This is my scenario:
I have 3 VF Componentes: A, B and C

Those components are shown as tabs of a parent VF Page, "Container". They share some heavy processing functions, and they also have some own functions.

My first approach was creating a virtual ExtensionClass for all of them, where I could store the main attributes and functions for all of the three VF Components. So basically it remains:

```
public virtual ExtensionClass{
    attribute1;

    heavyFoo(){
        // ...
    }
}

public class A extends ExtensionClass{ 
    A(){
        // define data using attribute1
    }
}
public class B extends ExtensionClass{ 
    B(){
        // define data using attribute1
    }
}
public class C extends ExtensionClass{
    C(){
        // define data using attribute1
    } 
}
```

But I realized that when "Container" is constructed, it creates 3 instances for "ExtensionClass", and so heavyFoo() run 3 times. So I thought about moving the common data to the virtual class, and pass the data through params like this

```
<!-- Container -->
<apex:page controller="ContainerCtr">
    <c:A _attribute="{!attribute1}" _resultOfHeavy="{!getHeavyFoo}" />

    <c:B _attribute="{!attribute1}" _resultOfHeavy="{!getHeavyFoo}" />
    
    <c:C _attribute="{!attribute1}" _resultOfHeavy="{!getHeavyFoo}" />
    
</apex:page>


public class ContainerCtr{
    attribute1{get;set;}

    heavyFoo(){
      // return heavy SOQL data
    }
}
```

BUT NOW, the problem is that because of the execution order of the constructors, the constructors of A,B and C cannot use the params.

Having this model, how can I achieve a good encapsulation and avoid running several times the same heavy logic?

Comment: You won't be able to use the constructor of the component for any of this but you can likely use the setter in the component that is paired with the `assignTo` action on the component's `_resultOfHeavy` attribute. You could implement some logic there but be mindful that the setter could be called multiple times and your code should account for that scenario.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense but it seems you went a touch too far on your simplifications into pseudo-code for us to pinpoint your struggle.

Comment: if you make `heavyFoo()` a lazy load, it will only be called once

Comment: I added an answer here long ago after playing with passing around references between VF and Components - it may be helpful, or another option for you. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9386/660